# Entity Framework linq and group by count

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is my current table. I am trying to find the rows where `NotificatinsID` is not null and get their count. The expected result and class are below.

```
ID  UserCreated NotificationsID
1      Test          89
2      Test1         NULL
3      Test2         NULL
4      Test3         91
4      Test4         92
4      Test5         93
5      Test6         94
5      Test7         95

public class DataModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String UserCreated { get; set; }
    public int? NotificatinsID { get; set; }
}
```

Expected Result

```
ID   NotificationsCount
1        1
2        0
3        0
4        3
5        2
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: If you want to use LINQ to count groups then learn how to do it and do it. If what you try doesn't work as expected, then you have a question you can ask here. SO is not a place to get people to write your code for you so you don't have to learn how.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want the NotificationsCount to be null as a possible result. It might make more sense to be 0 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
var result = models.GroupBy(m => m.ID)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, NotificationsCount = g
            .Where(m => m.NotificatinsID.HasValue).Count() }).ToList();
```

We use `GroupBy` to group the items by their ID and then check `.NotificatinsID.HasValue` to only count the ones whose `NotificatinsID` property is not null.

Comment: The indenting/line breaking makes that one hard to read